# Abrir enlace de iframe en la misma ventana y no adentro del marco

Tags: php, iframe

Tengo un problema, hice un iframe de un archivo .php de mi web, para que no se me mezclen los estilos, es algo provisional, este archivo, tiene una etiqueta  el problema que tengo es que al darle click, me lo abre adentro del marco, y yo necesito que se abra en la misma ventana, probé con "_self" pero no hace nada, solo "_blank" pero esto no me gusta como queda, parece que se abre una ventana con publicidad.
Acá dejo como arme mi iframe:

```html
<?php
$fecha = date("d-m-Y");

switch ($fecha) {
    case "11-09-2018":
 if ($quediaes=="Tue") {
  echo'<center>
     <div class="resp-container">
      <iframe src="/superliga/seleccionindex.php" height="90%" width="400px" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
     </div>
   </center>';
  }
  break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2656798/323149) respuesta, pon lo siguiente en el head del iframe:

```
<base target="_parent">
```

Comment: Eso me lleva al link del iframe

Comment: Se supone que el tag base hace que se abran los enlaces por defecto como se indique en dicho tag pero si no funciona otras respuestas en ese mismo post hablan de usar target="_parent" en los enlaces